# Discrete Math - Translating from English to Logic

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Use E(x) for “x is even” and O(x) for “x is odd.”

Question: One more than any odd number is an even number.

Answer: ∀x  [O(x) ⇒ E(x+1)]

Could anyone verify my answer please?
Thank you

Comment: Hi, welcome.  I take it that the task is to translate the sentence from English to logic?

Comment: @MatthewLeingang yes. sorry for not clarifying

Comment: What you've written is correct